# Folder color extension... doesn't change color

Tags: gnome, nautilus, themes, directory, colors

I have installed the `folder-color` package from the Ubuntu repositories as well as the PPA, run the command `nautilus -q`, rebooted, changed themes (I use `papirus-adapta-nokto` but it doesn't work in `ubuntu-mono-dark` either, nor any of their analogs), rebooted, and repeatedly tried to change the color of a folder.

Simply put, the option to change the color is there; it just doesn't do anything! (?)

[image]

I am running Ubuntu 17.10 amd64 and using the Gnome Desktop Environment with Nautilus.

Edit: I have just *clean-installed* Ubuntu 18.04. Folder color still doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## tl;dr do `sudo chown $USER:$USER /home/$USER/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/*`

I have finally found an answer to this question!

I ended up reinstalling Ubuntu, then, when *that* didn't work, deleting configuration files from my home directory. Eventually, folder-color started working...

Until three days ago, when it stopped for no apparent reason.

This time, I read the source code. folder-color uses gio metadata to store folder custom icons, so I ran the `gio info` command on `~/Documents`, and got this:

```
(gio info:15425): GVFS-WARNING **: 19:45:44.340: can't init metadata tree /home/$USER/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home: open: Permission denied
```

I then did `ll ~/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home`, and sure enough, it and two other files were owned by root.

Doing `sudo chown $USER:$USER /home/$USER/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/*` fixed all of those, and folder-color immediately began working again.

I can only guess that this happens when Nautilus is run as root (you shouldn't do that anyway `:P`).